# ng-include stretches page height - how can I make normal column the same height as the ng-include area?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In my Angular app, I am using `ng-include` to include a template in my page that dynamically adds content. What happens is that this area becomes even longer than the `html` and `body` elements it lives in.

***[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fm9vw2x/)***

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  height: 100%
}
#left {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
}
#right {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" class="row">
  <div id="left" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p>Item 1</p>
      <p>Item 2</p>
      <p>Item 3</p>
      <p>Item 4</p>
      <p>Item 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div id="somethingLong">
      <div id="bigItem">
        <h2> My big Car </h2>

      </div>
      <div id="bigItem">
        <h2> My big house </h2>

      </div>
      <div id="bigItem">
        <h2> My big Paycheck </h2>

      </div>
      <div>
        <div ng-include src="'template.html'"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- template -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
  <div>
    <h1>Angular Script</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Angular Script</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Angular Script</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Angular Script</h1>
  </div>
</script>
```

**How can I get my `left` sidebar to be as long as the `right` sidebar?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to angularjs but by this bootstrap's [bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8959), that creates the following CSS for the row class:

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

If you add:

```
.row {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

The problem is solved.

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fm9vw2x/1/)